# JQuery selector for table cells except first/last row/column

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

is there a way to directly select all 'inner' table cells (`<td>` elements) of a table (i.e. all cells **except** the ones in the first and last row and column) using a jquery selector expression?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selectors, like this

```
$('table td:not(:first-child, :last-child)')
```

To exclude first/last rows as well:

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child, :last-child) td:not(:first-child, :last-child)')
```

Comment: If you want to skip the first and last table rows *and* table cells,  `table tr:not(:first-child, :last-child) td:not(:first-child, :last-child)` should work.

Comment: I think OP wants to exclude the first/last rows as well. :o) EDIT: Can't tell from the question, but perhaps `<th>` cells should be considered too.

Comment: @patrick - good call, though I think `<th>` would just be on that first/excluded row, added the row-excluding version

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right about the `<th>`, although I may be inclined to use `:first,:last` for the `<tr>` in case there are multiple table sections. Likely not the case here, but thought I'd note it anyway. :o)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using <th> so this solution works perfectly for me!

Comment: @patrick - I suppose it depends on your case, the downside of `:first` and `:last` is with multiple tables you'd not get what you're after either...I guess it's just a matter of the specific markup this is targeting.

Comment: Nick - Ah, good point. I was only giving consideration to a single table. Hadn't considered multiple.

Comment: I suggest `tr>td` to avoid problems with nested tables. Also note this will block the first and last row in each section, not the whole table, when multiple sections (`<tbody>` et al) are in use. If that's not what you want, consider getting the table DOM object and iterating over all but the first and last of `table.rows` and `row.cells`.

Comment: @bobince - That would still find them even nested (since they are direct children of a `<tr>` as well), you would need the full direct-child selector chain to only get the current table.

Comment: Yeah, though the current particular example doesn't specify a particular table so it kind of doesn't make any difference there. The full child selector chain is a good idea, but then you have to include `tbody`, and, if using XHTML, actually include the `<tbody>` in the markup (since HTML and XHTML differ on whether missing tbodies are implied). This sort of thing is why I like the DOM version ;-)

Comment: I want to clone the first header row with the `header` class except the last column of that row only. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#table_name tr td:not(:first-child)').each(function () {
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
                });
```

Here example how to Skip 1st td of a table(table_name) .U can write :last-child to skip last td to do some task.