# JQuery fire click event on clicking li

Tags: jquery

I have ul li list and I want to fire a jQuery click event on clicking "li" element but except the first li/first-child. So suppose if I have a below list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sample_list li").click(function(){
            alert("hello");
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="sample_list">
    <li>First Child</li>
    <li>Second Child</li>
    <li>Third Child</li>
    <li>Fourth Child</li>
</ul>
```

Now when I click other li's except the first one I should get the alert box. I think I have to write something in this **$(".sample_list li")**, something like **$(".sample_list li:other-child")** but not sure. Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I love that this question has four answers in about four minutes. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".sample_list li:not(:eq(0))").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yPCgT/)

---

```
$(".sample_list li:not(:first-child)").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yPCgT/1/)

---

```
$(".sample_list li").slice(1).click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yPCgT/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways, one of such is [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) .. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/H82Gq/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sample_list li:not(:eq(0))").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sample_list li").not(':eq(0)').click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Copying directly from [JQuery selector for table cells except first/last row/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027855/jquery-selector-for-table-cells-except-first-last-row-column), what about

```
$('ul li:not(:first-child)')
```

Haven't tried it but it looks like you're trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sample_list li").click(function(){
        if (this.previousSibling != null)
            alert("hello");
    });
});
</script>
```